# get distance by array of latitude and longitude on google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var path = [
    { "lat": 43.00678, "lng": -89.53743 },
    { "lat": 43.00656, "lng": -89.53732 },
    { "lat": 43.005878, "lng": -89.53797 },
    { "lat": 43.005344, "lng": -89.53684 },
    { "lat": 43.003834, "lng": -89.535400 },
    { "lat": 43.003692, "lng": -89.533834 },
    { "lat": 43.006384, "lng": -89.533796 },
    { "lat": 43.0120328, "lng": -89.533667 },
    { "lat": 43.015931, "lng": -89.533635 },
    { "lat": 43.023030, "lng": -89.5335390 },
    { "lat": 43.032010, "lng": -89.533249 },
    { "lat": 43.040221, "lng": -89.5329596 },
    { "lat": 43.04632176, "lng": -89.5318224 },
    { "lat": 43.052562, "lng": -89.5277883 },
    { "lat": 43.060300, "lng": -89.52759526 },
    { "lat": 43.06401556, "lng": -89.5268978 },
    { "lat": 43.06681381, "lng": -89.5241620 },
    { "lat": 43.0714224, "lng": -89.52499888 },
    { "lat": 43.07468269, "lng": -89.52698371 },
    { "lat": 43.07490213, "lng": -89.53292749 },
    { "lat": 43.076203059, "lng": -89.53269145 },
    { "lat": 43.0765949, "lng": -89.5314576 },
    { "lat": 43.0793377, "lng": -89.53323862 },
    { "lat": 43.0803799, "lng": -89.53454754 },
    { "lat": 43.0835927, "lng": -89.5340754 },
    { "lat": 43.08458789, "lng": -89.5334853 },
    { "lat": 43.0844468, "lng": -89.53403256 },
    { "lat": 43.08445469, "lng": -89.5352985 },
    { "lat": 43.084619242, "lng": -89.5358993791 }
];
```

this is Javascript array by this I want to draw a polyline on google map for vehicle tracking and find **total distance** of vehicle trip.

Comment: google has an API to calculate the distance ([with a few limitations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits)): [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

Comment: Hi @sarath, can you provide sample code on how to calculate distance using Snap-to-Road ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple way to calculate the total distance of the path is looping through the path array and calculate the distance between each points with
[Haversine formula: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula) or with
`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLngA, latLngB);` method and summarize the results.
(latter case you must load the geometry library: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry`)
e.g.:

```
function calcPathLength(path){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
        var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(path[i].lat(), path[i].lng());
        var pos2 = new google.maps.LatLng(path[i + 1].lat(), path[i + 1].lng());
        total += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pos1, pos2);
    };
    return total;
};
```

This gives you only an approximate result, because the distances between two points sometimes too big and the path does not follow the roads precisely.

Another approach to solve this problem is using the [Google Maps Roads API snap to roads feature. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) In this case we still have the problem with the distances between the points, because the documentation says that the consecutive pairs of points should be within 300m of each other. I think the best we can do is adding more points to the path.
In the following example I show you how to display and calculate the total distance of your path. I modified the google's Snap to Road demo for your purpose. Please note that the roads API requires an API key, so you should replace the YOUR_API_KEY with your key.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Roads API Demo</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>
var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; //Replace it with your key
            //This is the path you provided
var path = [
    { "lat": 43.00678, "lng": -89.53743 },
    { "lat": 43.00656, "lng": -89.53732 },
    { "lat": 43.005878, "lng": -89.53797 },
    { "lat": 43.005344, "lng": -89.53684 },
    { "lat": 43.003834, "lng": -89.535400 },
    { "lat": 43.003692, "lng": -89.533834 },
    { "lat": 43.006384, "lng": -89.533796 },
    { "lat": 43.0120328, "lng": -89.533667 },
    { "lat": 43.015931, "lng": -89.533635 },
    { "lat": 43.023030, "lng": -89.5335390 },
    { "lat": 43.032010, "lng": -89.533249 },
    { "lat": 43.040221, "lng": -89.5329596 },
    { "lat": 43.04632176, "lng": -89.5318224 },
    { "lat": 43.052562, "lng": -89.5277883 },
    { "lat": 43.060300, "lng": -89.52759526 },
    { "lat": 43.06401556, "lng": -89.5268978 },
    { "lat": 43.06681381, "lng": -89.5241620 },
    { "lat": 43.0714224, "lng": -89.52499888 },
    { "lat": 43.07468269, "lng": -89.52698371 },
    { "lat": 43.07490213, "lng": -89.53292749 },
    { "lat": 43.076203059, "lng": -89.53269145 },
    { "lat": 43.0765949, "lng": -89.5314576 },
    { "lat": 43.0793377, "lng": -89.53323862 },
    { "lat": 43.0803799, "lng": -89.53454754 },
    { "lat": 43.0835927, "lng": -89.5340754 },
    { "lat": 43.08458789, "lng": -89.5334853 },
    { "lat": 43.0844468, "lng": -89.53403256 },
    { "lat": 43.08445469, "lng": -89.5352985 },
    { "lat": 43.084619242, "lng": -89.5358993791 }
  ]; 
var map;
var snappedCoordinates = [];
var extendedPath = [];
var startMarker;
var endMarker;
var startIcon = 'https://mts.googleapis.com/maps/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png&text=A&psize=16&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff333333&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1';
var endIcon = 'https://mts.googleapis.com/maps/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-b.png&text=B&psize=16&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff333333&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1';
var infowindow;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 43.040221, lng: -89.5329596}
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(path[0].lat, path[0].lng),
    icon: startIcon
  });
  endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(path[path.length - 1].lat, path[path.length - 1].lng),
    icon: endIcon
  })
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: ''});
  extendedPath = getExtendedPath(path); //Let's extend the original path
  runSnapToRoad(extendedPath);
}
function getExtendedPath(path) {
  var extPath = path;
  var newPath = [];
  while (pointsTooFar(extPath)){  //We do it while all the distance between points are less then 250 meters
      newPath = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < extPath.length - 1; i++) {
        var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(extPath[i].lat, extPath[i].lng);
        var pos2 = new google.maps.LatLng(extPath[i + 1].lat, extPath[i + 1].lng);
        var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pos1, pos2);
        newPath.push(extPath[i]);
        if (dist > 250) {  //If the distance between two points is greater than 250 metres we add an intermediate point 
           var insPos = { "lat": (extPath[i].lat + extPath[i + 1].lat)/2, "lng": (extPath[i].lng + extPath[i + 1].lng)/2 };
            newPath.push(insPos);
        }
      }
      newPath.push(extPath[extPath.length-1]);
      extPath = newPath;
  }
  return extPath;
}

function pointsTooFar(pointPath){
  var tooFar = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < pointPath.length - 1; i++) {
    var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(pointPath[i].lat, pointPath[i].lng);
    var pos2 = new google.maps.LatLng(pointPath[i + 1].lat, pointPath[i + 1].lng);
    var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pos1, pos2);
    if (dist > 250){
        tooFar = true;
        break;
    };
  }; 
  return tooFar;
}

// Snap a user-created polyline to roads and draw the snapped path
function runSnapToRoad(path) {
  var pathValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    pathValues.push((new google.maps.LatLng(path[i].lat, path[i].lng)).toUrlValue());
  }
  $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads', {
    interpolate: true,
    key: apiKey,
    path: pathValues.join('|')
  }, function(data) {
    processSnapToRoadResponse(data);
    drawSnappedPolyline();
    calcPathLength(snappedCoordinates);
  });
}

// Store snapped polyline returned by the snap-to-road service.
function processSnapToRoadResponse(data) {
  snappedCoordinates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.snappedPoints.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        data.snappedPoints[i].location.latitude,
        data.snappedPoints[i].location.longitude);
    snappedCoordinates.push(latlng);
  }
}

// Draws the snapped polyline (after processing snap-to-road response).
function drawSnappedPolyline() {
  var snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: snappedCoordinates,
    strokeColor: '#00B3FD',
    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
    strokeWeight: 5
  });
  snappedPolyline.setMap(map);
}

function calcPathLength(cPath){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cPath.length - 1; i++) {
        var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(cPath[i].lat(), cPath[i].lng());
        var pos2 = new google.maps.LatLng(cPath[i + 1].lat(), cPath[i + 1].lng());
        total += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pos1, pos2);
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pos1, pos2).toFixed(0));
    };
    infowindow.setContent('<h4>Total length of the path: ' + (total / 1609.34).toFixed(1) + ' miles</h4>');
    infowindow.open(map, endMarker);
};

$(window).load(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.